# Non-numeric argument to binary operator aes function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've done quite a bit of research on this error, and in all other cases, it seems like this error shows up when there is a missing bracket or paren. However, I have scoured my code and I'm not seeing that anywhere. It seems like the code is not reading my full aes object before throwing the error:

I am creating a function that will create a ggplot object that draws reference lines and an annotation on my chart. Here is the function:

```
create_geom_segments <- function(labelx, labely, text_label, color) {
 geom_obj <- (
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=labely, xend =labelx, yend=labely), col = color, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=labelx, y=0,xend=labelx, yend=labely), col = color, linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", x=labelx, y=labely + 3, label=text_label) 
)

return(geom_obj)    
}
```

When I run this with generic inputs, such as

```
test <- create_geom_segments(0,10, "test", "red")
```

I get:

```
Error in geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = labely, xend = labelx,  : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am building this function after creating these objects successfully outside of a function using this:

```
new_graph <- (p + geom_segment(aes(x=0,y = x, xend = days_x, yend =x), col = "red", linetype = 'dashed')  + geom_segment(aes(x=days_x, y = 0, xend = days_x, yend = x)
          , col = "red", linetype = 'dashed') + annotate("text", x= days_x, y = x + 3, label = text ))
```

I did not get any errors with this code and it worked as expected.

Comment: also, you probably want to avoid `+`, use `list(geom_xxx(), geom_yyy())` instead.

Comment: Thanks, both! baptiste got this error to go away, and then it wasn't reading my inputs correctly, which was fixed by switching to aes_string. My only problem now is that the annotate() function is not reading the function inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: annotate is just a wrapper for geoms, with `inherit.aes=FALSE`, you can replace it with a proper geom layer.

Comment: you may want to post your solution below, and accept it.

Comment: thanks, this is my first time posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full solution here, thanks to baptiste and joran:

```
create_geom_segments <- function(labelx, labely, text_label, line_color, xoffset, yoffset) {
geom_obj <- list(
geom_segment(aes_string(x=0, y=labely, xend =labelx, yend=labely), col =
    line_color, linetype =      "dashed"),
geom_segment(aes_string(x=labelx, y=0,xend=labelx, yend=labely), col =
    line_color, linetype = "dashed"),
geom_text(aes_string(x=labelx + xoffset, y=labely + yoffset), 
    label = text_label, data = data.frame()) 
)
return(geom_obj)    
}
```

Changes made:

Changed from using + syntax between the geom_segment objects to creating a list. FYI when calling these objects from the returned object, I used result[[i]]. This removed the original error I reported. The next issue was that it wasn't recognizing my function inputs labelx and labely.

Changed from aes() to aes_string() to get the function to recognize function inputs.

Lastly, the annotate wasn't recognizing the function inputs. Changed to geom_text as written above to fix. (also added offsets to the function so my labels weren't on top of the lines.